# ServiceHost Open Delay

Tags: wcf, http, delay, servicehost

Since updating my workstation with windows 7 ultimate (from XP), I experience a delay of about 40 seconds to after calling Open() on an instantiated ServiceHost.

When I run the exe with the same config on the host windows server it opens immediately. Any ideas about this behavior on my workstation?

Running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, Windows 7 Ultimate x64, 8gig RAM.

Update....
I found that removing the 
1. service mex endpoint (leaving a single net.tcp endpoint)
2. service host http base address
3. service behavior httpGetEnabled

resolves the issue. If I change the net.tcp endpoint to use basicHttpBinding, Open takes 40 seconds. But why is there a 40 second delay to set up the endpoint with the http endpoint (mex or service-contract)?

Comment: I'd suspect DNS/NetBIOS issues. Try to hardcode the server's IP address in `hosts` and see if the issue disappears. If it does, it's probably a hostname resolution problem.